# Site-To-Site VPN: Remote Windows Server Can Ping But Can't Share Resources?

Tags: windows, site-to-site-vpn, mikrotik

I have a site-to-site VPN tunnel between two MicroTik routers in two separate locations. Location A where the server is located is on the subnet 192.168.33.0 and Location B is 192.168.1.0. The VPN tunnel seems to be working just fine -- I can ping any node on the network between both locations successfully, however utilizing network resources such as mapping drives, or even basic network discovery between sites just doesn't seem to work. I can also ping my Windows 2012 DC but cannot add any computers on the remote site to it, nevertheless can ping the server just fine. Did I overlook something setting up this VPN tunnel? Traffic seems to flow through it just fine. I'm thinking its a Windows thing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Also might be worth noting that if I turn off the site-to-site VPN on the routers and simply forward the ports needed for the Windows 2012 server to manage VPN, it works perfectly--shared resources, network discovery and all.

Comment: Well, the problem here is that I didn't NAT port 445, but I need to send that 445 traffic to the VPN tunnel, but not sure how to do this the right way.